# DTO for classes with few properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, design-patterns, dto

I have a LinqToSql (or it could be EF) ASP.NET MVC project with 3 layers.

Is it usual (or correct) to create a DTO class to map a LinqToSql class that has a few properties, let's say 3 properties: id, name, status?

Or is it best to use this LinqToSql class direct on my View?

What are your opinions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your programm works without using DTO then you do not need it. Just Keep it simple stupid :)